# Entity object's navigation property set to null after Deserialization

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, serialization, deserialization

I am working on a WPF application, the architect is

WPF->WCF->DAL

the issue is when i call the WCF method, it returns the object. Everything upto WCF level works just fine, but while returning the object, after WCF my navigation properties are setting to null.

i am returning the object(POCO) object of Department class, and its navigation property is Employees. I verfied the [DataMember] attribute, this is not the case. But as soon as it reaches the MainUI its Employees property is setting to null.

The code of my navigation property looks like that

Thanks

Comment: Can you put the code for your query

Comment: Is it WCF service code? Why are you using `ToFixupCollection` instead of including all details in single query? Is `Employees` mapped relation? Can you show code of your entities? How did you create WCF client? Btw. can you check transported message to validate if WCF service sends your data (use [message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) for that)?

Comment: Also don't call `department.FirstOrDefault()` twice. It executes database query twice. You need to call it only once and use the result.

Comment: Hi Ladislav, i've added lot of code in my question, hope this helps

Comment: The code of `ToFixUpCollection` is still missing, but I see that the setter of `FixupCollection` doesn't enumerate the collection. Like Ladislav said, you should use `FirstOrDefault` only once and enumerate the `Employees` collection to load it.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this happens because the navigation properties are lazy loaded. When you try to access them they cannot be loaded because the context is disposed. You should load them eagerly or explicitly when you load the main property.

Eager loading:

```
from d in context.Department.Include("Employees")
select d;
```

Explicit loading:

```
var departments = (from d in context.Department
                   select d).ToList();
departments.ForEach(e => e.EmployeesReference.Load());
```

**EDIT AFTER QUESTION EDIT**

The problem could be the line:

```
department.FirstOrDefault().Employees = employees.ToFixupCollection();
```

Try changing it to:

```
department.FirstOrDefault().Employees = employees.ToList<Employee>();
```

Comment: Nah, i checked it and re-check it, but no use,

Comment: @MSingh Can you post your code? It would help greatly. Note: if you inspect the navigation property in debug mode, it will explicitly load the property.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, i put some code in query, kindly verify. Thanks

Comment: @MSingh What does `ToFixupCollection` do? Does it enumarate the query?

Comment: ToFixUpCollection is the custom class that inherits from Observable Collection