# Navigation properties is being null while retrieving data using Join in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have written following linq query to retrieve customer information and other information of customer from other entity.
e.g :

```
var customers = CreateObjectSet<Customer>().Include(address =>address.Address).
                                            AsQueryable();
var OtherEntityies = CreateObjectSet<XYZ>().AsQueryable();

return (from other in OtherEntityies 
        join customer in customers
        on new { other.KeyID, other.TypeID }
        equals new { 
             KeyID = customer.CustomerID, 
             SecUserTypeID = (int)Type.CUSTOMER 
        }                     
        select new CustomerInfo {
             Customer=customer,
             Email = other.Email       
        }
       ).SingleOrDefault();
```

To retrieving customer information, I have created a Custom class `CustomerInfo`.
But problem is that after using JOIN expression, navigation property (`address.Address`) is being null from `Customer`, but sometimes it's working fine. I am not able to get the problem. Kindly help me out, how should write query so that I can get the navigation property with `Customer` entity after using JOIN.

Comment: Sorry I missed, just look at the following one return (from other in OtherEntityies join customer in customers on new { other.KeyID, other.TypeID } equals new { KeyID = customer.CustomerID, SecUserTypeID = (int)Type.CUSTOMER } select new CustomerInfo { Customer=customer, Email = other.Email } ).SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Once you do projection or manual join, eager loading (`Include`) is not performed. It is a "feature" (= by design) of entity framework.

What I don't understand is why it matters? You are selecting only email (by projecting it to `CustomerInfo`) so you don't need and you will never get `Address`.

Edit:

Use this to solve the problem:

```
    select new CustomerInfo {
         Customer=customer,
         Address = customer.Address,
         Email = other.Email       
    }
```

You will not need `Include` any more.

Comment: Sorry I missed, just look at the following one                                                                   return (from other in OtherEntityies 
        join customer in customers
        on new { other.KeyID, other.TypeID }
        equals new { 
             KeyID = customer.CustomerID, 
             SecUserTypeID = (int)Type.CUSTOMER 
        }                     
        select new CustomerInfo { Customer=customer,
             Email = other.Email       
        }
       ).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: But Ladislav, what if user just want to return a POCO entity, it have everything it required in navigational properties Kindly give the answer in the context of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265789/entity-objects-navigation-property-set-to-null-after-deserialization

Comment: @MSingh: Your problem is completely different and not related to the problem where `Include` doesn't work with custom joins or projections.

Comment: Ladislav, whenever i stuck in any issue related to Entity Framework, you rescued me, will you please respond to that question also.